# mac version control software?

Tags: macos

anyone know any good mac version control software? if so why is do you reccomend it, dont mind paying a little money for the software

**edit**: thanks everyone for the information so its come down to Mercurial vs SubVersionsapp (SVN)

Comment: What do you mean with that? Something like CVS, SVN, git, etc.?

Comment: yer basically, so if your developing a project it will automatically keep track of the changes you have made from version 1.0.0 to version 1.0.1 for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use SVN ([mac client](http://versionsapp.com/)) at work from all different platforms.  Git ([mac client](http://gitx.frim.nl/)) or Mercurial ([mac client](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/)) would work as well.  Personally, I wouldn't pay for something like this unless you're using an IDE that has integrated SCM as part of it's paid offering.  This is an area where the free/open source solutions have actually been preferable to paid solutions for many years.  If you don't feel comfortable supporting it (maintaining the repository, backups, etc.), you might want to look at a hosting service for the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://versionsapp.com/ for an SVN client

For git, check out the answers to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455698/best-visual-client-for-git-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a GUI client you have [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) for git but if you're looking for the actual vcs i think most of the major ones have a git port.

Answer (score 0):

[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) works really well on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Currently Xcode has CVS and Subversion integrated into it, and I wouldn't recommend CVS.  Maybe a future version of Xcode will support more version control systems.

Comment: Yep! Xcode 4 (currently in private beta) is known to support Git :-)

Comment: @Zheileman: Actually, I knew that, but I try to respect NDAs. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you go for Mercurial (which I personally recommend) or Git you should take a look at [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) as a very Mac-like client software.

It is quite easy to use, very stable and best of all even free (sponsored by Atlassian).